# extras_require with readthedocs and poetry

Tags: python, setup.py, read-the-docs, python-poetry

I use poetry to build my package with cython extensions, so install package flag is enabled. I'd like to host documentation via readthedocs. Poetry uses `build.py` file to generate `setup.py` with `poetry build` command. However readthedocs does not support `build.py` so I provided `setup.py` with following contents:

```
from setuptools import setup
from build import *

global setup_kwargs

setup_kwargs = {}

build(setup_kwargs)
setup(**setup_kwargs)
```

To get rid of `requirements.txt` file in docs folder, I would like to add `extras_require` parameter to setup, so the last line in `setup.py`:

```
setup(extras_require={'docs': ['toml']}, **setup_kwargs)
```

Readthedocs calls `/<path>/envs/latest/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade --upgrade-strategy eager --no-cache-dir .[docs]`

**WARNING:  does not provide the extra 'docs'** and importing toml from `docs/conf.py` fails

If I add extras to `pyproject.toml`:

```
[tool.poetry.extras]
docs = ['toml']
```

Warning disappears but still rtd fails to import toml.

My `.readthedocs.yml`:

```
version: 2

sphinx:
  configuration: docs/conf.py

formats: all

python:
  version: 3.7
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
      extra_requirements:
        - docs

submodules:
  include: all
```